# Python, quotes within a quote

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to build a nagios script but having an issues with a single quote inside a double one.

I am trying to pass the following:

```
select (select count(*) from v$session)/(select value from v$parameter where name = 'processes')*100 Percent from dual"
```

The select has to be quoted just like above.

I tried to pass this into the string in various ways:

```
line=select (select count(*) from v$session)/(select value from v$parameter where name = 'processes')*100 Percent from dual"
```

than created a command like this:

```
process= '"' + line + '"'

p = subprocess.Popen( line.split())
```

Unfortunately `line.split` doesn't do correct quote parsing.

The "select" must be quoted, and `'processes'` must be quoted in a single quote.

Any suggestion how I could do this?

#### Update:

Apparently the issue is with the "split" process.  The sql statement has to be passed intact, and quoted as a single statement.  However I have pass quite a few complicated arguments and the `line.split` worked for that, until I run into this issue.

So the better question is how I can format the subprocess to send a whole string as well as a long list (about 5 string arguments) with it?

#### Update:

In case this helps someone.  Apparently with Popen you have to divide arguments and input.  So that for instance you can't send `"--test blah"`; it has to be `"--test", "blah"`.  This means that to send a string you have to split it.

However if a whole string is necessary you have to edit that and append to the list.

So for instance

```
a = "--test blah --something other"
b = a.split()
```

This will generate a list and `Popen` will handle it fine (with `subprocess.Popen(b)`).

However if you need to also send a whole string like this:

```
sql = "select count(*) from v$session"
```

you can't just add this to the "a string" as in `a + sql`.  You need to do something like this:

```
b.append(sql)
```

which will add the whole string and then `Popen` knows how to handle it.

Unfortunately (at least to the best of my knowledge) it is not possible to send `Popen` a string such as:

```
c = a + sql
subprocess.Popen(c)
```

and get a response unless you use `shell=True`.  However, then you get return statement and NOT output.

Hope this will help someone in similar situation as I was.

Comment: I think you missed some quote characters in your code sample.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you're asking, then you want to be able to have quotes around select, and also escape the single quotes around processes.

Try using [triple quotes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
line=""" "select (select count(*) from v$session)/(select value from v$parameter where name = \'processes\')*100 Percent from dual" """
```

...which prints:

```
"select (select count(*) from v$session)/(select value from v$parameter where name = 'processes')*100 Percent from dual"
```

Comment: Still no dice:
UNKNOWN - got no valid response for select - ORA-00936: missing expression (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 6 in 'select<*>')

when I do line.split the formating doesn't quite look as it will work.
'select', '(select', 'count(*)', 'from', 'v$session)/(select', 'value', 'from', 'v$parameter', 'where', 'name', '=', "'processes')*100", 'Percent', 'from', 'dual'

Seems to me that maybe I should use something other than line.split in the argument field?

Comment: I'll add in an Oracle tag for your question in a moment since this does relate to an Oracle query.  As for your issue, can you clarify in your question as to how you're connecting to this database?

Comment: It is perl script which uses DBD and DBI libraries to send sql statements to the oracle database.  The quotes have to be exact when send to the script.

Comment: Looking at the DBI documentation, it seems that the string needs to be around the *entire* expression.  Is this the case?  If so I'd say that splitting the string would definitely not be the right way to go, since it appears that the entire string needs to be fit through all at once.  Furthermore, I encourage you to update your question to include this new information, as it will help others with your question (when I head off to sleep).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are 100% right.  The issue is not with the quotes but rather with the split.  I updated the question to reflect that.  I had a feeling that this might be the case but have no clue how to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

- use triple quotes:

`"""valid single ' and double quotes " in string"""`

or

`'''valid single ' and double quotes " in string'''`

- if you need use quotes in single quotes, escape them with backslash:

`"valid \" string"`